# Checking if a file exists using JSTL in a JSP page

Tags: jsp, jstl, file-exists

Is possible to check in JSTL if a file exists (exactly an image):
Simply issue of viewing profile image. If is in the folder with images profile image show the profile image, if not show default image.

This is a pseudo code:

```
if file img/1.jpg exist:
<img src="img/1.jpg" />
if file img/1.jpg doesn't exist
<img src="img/default_image.jpg" />
```

Note: I am prohibited from using scriptlets. I have to use JSTL in JSP.

Comment: Been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624657/how-can-you-check-if-a-file-exists-before-including-importing-it-in-jsp

Comment: @vector I saw that but I don't see the answer in it. It doesn't help me so it's the reason why I asked. And I also think that it's different problem, I don't want to include anything. So is it possible or not?

Comment: @vector Ok, so it's imposible to do it this way. Thanks. I'll try to do it somehow in Servlet.

Comment: @vector Can you copy your last comment as an answer, I'll accept it as answer cause its exact answer to the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not if you have to use straight JSTL, you could do it in a scriptlet, but you'll be advised that it's not recommended